# iOS Google Plus API - Sharing or Logging In without going to Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, google-api, google-plus

So far everything I've found on the subject, is a NO.

My app works fine when the user logs in and shares, but both actions require mobile safari, which is a less than ideal experience for the user, has anyone found a way to either share a post or log in to Google + using a UIWebView or GET/POST?.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you found an answer for this ?

Comment: No I have not, I believe it is possible though, but I stopped trying since it really looks like google doesn't want you to do it anyway, so it will probably stop working in the future.

Comment: @Oscar Gomez : Did your problem solved? If yes then you can describe.I am also getting this problem.

Comment: @FastTrack nope could not solve my problem, we will have to wait till google + dev team solves this issue.

Comment: @OscarGomez It has been a while now since Ponting asked the question, so have you by any chance found a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can SignIn via Google+ into UIWebView.

```
 GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *_googlePlusCtrl = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                                                   initWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
                                                   clientID:GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_ID
                                                   clientSecret:GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_SECRET
                                                   keychainItemName:@"GooglePlus_Sample_App"
                                                   delegate:self
                          finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone :  The above hint is not working for me in UIWebView. You can describe in detail.

Comment: This method will be enough for open Google+ SignIn page on UIWebVIew. If you use this method and pass delegate as self, then on that controller's view, a Google+ SignIn page will open and it makes its own web view. We do not need to provide one. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone can u please explain how to share without leaving the app

Comment: Sorry Shan. I am also working on that and couldn't find a way to share on google+ without leaving the app. If you find a way to doing this, then please tell me also.

Comment: @MohdHaider Great but after all that, how do you pass the accessToken back to the Google Plus SDK?

Comment: @JackDawson Hey Can you help me to open google + sign in page within app. I have used this method but Nothing happend.

Comment: will you please post the exactly how to open GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch  in web view?

Answer (score 6):

Easiest answer is no, as you say. The SDK will actually try to fall back through the following:

1. Log in via Google+ app (this is the nice result, but requires having the Google+ app installed)
2. Log in via Chrome
3. Log in via Mobile Safari

You can control the first part with the attemptSSO flag on the GPPSignIn object - if you set that to NO it wont try to use the Google+ app. You'll generally want it to try the Google+ app first. Sharing always happens via the web (chrome/safari) with the current API version (1.2.1) though.

Comment: Check my answer below. It is possible

Answer (score 2):

Well that's the thing. It's possible. First step - download sample project from here - https://github.com/emysa341/Login-with-gmail-google-g--using-oath-2.0-protocol. Second step, in the response- connection did finish loading, make another request - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%@ . Use the access token you got from the 1st request. Now in the response, you will get the user data. Also if you need the user's email, change the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email".

Comment: So how do you then pass back the accessToken to the Google Plus SDK? I ask this because while your post was great, ONLY the Google Plus SDK can actually POST to Google Plus. So is there a way to just pass back the accessToken to the Google Plus SDK once you have it?