# Sharing on Google+ in iOS without leaving App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-plus

Sorry for my English.

We can share the link on Google+ by using GPPShare class in Google+ iOS SDK but here we need to move to safari browser for this.

I also see that Flipboard App for iPhone/iPad do the sharing on Google+ without leaving the Flipboard app.

Do anyone know how to share the information on Google+ without leaving the App.

I am stuck now. If anyone have any clue, then please let me know as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for that. It is not the answer that i was expecting. I already told about that Flipboard Application for iPhone/iPad already use this solution but i do not know how they do it. If anyone have any clue, then please let me know.

Comment: have you managed to get an actual answer for this ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please go through this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436352/ios-google-plus-api-sharing-or-logging-in-without-going-to-safari ). Here you will get my answer for resolving this.