# sharing on google Plus stream without showing sharing dialog box

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Google Plus sharing.

Hi!
in my app i have integrated google + using google developer site' tutorials. it singned in and sharing on google + successfully .when user taped to share button a share dialog box is open and has to tap share button on that and after sharing it return to app.

but i required that when user taped to share button in my app . it should not to show any sharing dialog but share on successfully on Google + in background of showing my own loading view.how can i do this
Please help me with a full description or some tutorials on that

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi sundeep, can u please tell how to post public share using single share button created by me ... ?

Comment: @Shan i dont know yet .please tell me if you know anything about this

Comment: as you say @Prisoner , ya i accept,but how they did in flipboard app they are just providing a single share button to post on google plus stream ..?shan                    .so please tell me if you solved this

Comment: Seriously, i tried, but can't find a way, but finally i integrate g+ using share dialog (as the docs tells we can't post directly its all read only).

Comment: see this answer, flipboard using some experimental api's that is not yet released by google. some guy answered me see my question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080780/is-it-possible-to-post-on-google-plus-directly-without-additional-share-dialog-o/18098477#comment26538064_18098477".

Comment: Thanks Shan .i see the link google provide special value for flipboard . if you find any notifications from google or anywhere about this please tell me also .and thanks you very much......

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. The current SDK uses `Google plus app installed on device OR Chrome OR Safari` for sharing.

For more refer

[Google + iPhone API sign in and share without leaving app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app)

[iOS Google Plus API - Sharing or Logging In without going to Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436352/ios-google-plus-api-sharing-or-logging-in-without-going-to-safari)

Comment: are you sure it is not possible given url could not help

Comment: my client want the same so please provide some more info if any and thanks a lot for responding.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is deliberate - Google is trying to avoid frictionless sharing of content, which could be done without user consent, and spamming from junk posts. A single share button, implemented by you, is equivalent to allowing a program to submit whatever content it wants whenever it wants.

Google also wants to give people the ability to share content privately to one or several of their circles. Since you don't have access to what circles they may have, the only kind of sharing you can provide would be a public share, and this violates some of the privacy/sharing designs in Google+.

Comment: so public share can be done using a single share button created by me.i want share only some text and url...thanks for respond

Comment: i am in hurry cause my client want the same sharing on single button not showing sharing dialog box .is there any other way any suggestions please help...

Comment: As I said - Google sees this sort of sharing, without giving the viewer the option of sharing to a circle and without a comment, to be undesirable. There is no officially supported way of doing it.