# Is it possible to post on google plus directly without additional share dialog on web

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-api, google-plus

Is there any way to post directly on google Plus without extra share on web,

Now i am successfully posting on google Plus, every time i do like below, but

```
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
    // do additional stuff like filling the text message to "shareBuilder"
    ...
    ...
    //after this 
    [shareBuilder open]; //this leads to open web page where google provides its own share button
```

what my problem is, i want to post directly on google plus by bypassing this web page 
is there any way i can achieve this or this is the mandatory steps that we have to share through  this "web share".
i tried searching on it, but i did'nt find any thing. I need more help on this

Thanks in regards :)

Comment: Are you trying to post without the user consenting to share or are you trying to find another way to render the share dialog?

Comment: i want to share directly from application without entering to share dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is mandatory to use the share dialog so that the user is in control of all posts made to their stream.

Comment: But see if u hav flipboard app, in that there is no share dialog how do they are posting directly on g+ stream.. ? please help me on this

Comment: Flipboard has special and unique access to experimental Google+ APIs: http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/19/google-opens-its-api-to-flipboard-users-will-see-google-integration-soon/

Comment: Thank's for replay @ade, i tried to figure out how they implemented it well, thank u so much for giving the details .. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Google+ iOS SDK 1.4.0, you can now use native in-app sharing. This partially resolves I think one of your concerns about leaving your app. There is no Google+ API on ANY platform that will allow you to post directly to the stream though. Users always retain control over what they share on Google+.

To migrate to the [native sharing method](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share), use the following code:

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
// do additional stuff like filling the text message to "shareBuilder"
...
...
//after this 
[shareBuilder open]; // Open the native share dialog
```

You will also need to include some additional frameworks in your XCode project, see the list on the [getting started page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started).